# react-native app not generating icon (ANDROID)

Tags: android, react-native, icons

After the install of the **app-release.apk** on my device the icon is not visible anywhere in my menu (even installing it through the play store).

And also if I check it inside the settings>installed apps I can't launch the application by it's main activity. (I am able start the activity with adb shell)

Comment: once try to place your icon in drawable in simply

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Comment: The answer is related to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405020/android-cant-find-the-mainactivity-of-application